# Rails Nested Form - Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, mass-assignment

I've used the nested_form gem, whenever i try and submit something to my form i get the `Can't mass-assign protected attributes:items` message, even though i've already put `attr_accessible` in my models.

Form:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@goods_in) do |f| %>
...

<%= f.fields_for :items do |i| %>
<td><%= i.text_field :description, :autocomplete => :off%></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :quantity, :autocomplete => :off %></td>
<th><%= i.link_to_remove "Remove this item" %></th>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit :"Submit Delivery" %>
<% end %>
```

Goods In Model:class GoodsIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_many :items

```
attr_accessible :c4lpono, 
              :courier, 
              :deliverydate,  
              :deliverynoteno,  
              :destination,  
              :notes,  
              :quantity,  
              :signedby,
              :supplier_id,
              :partcode_ids

accepts_nested_attributes_for :supplier

validates :c4lpono, 
              :deliverydate,  
              :deliverynoteno,  
              :destination,  
              :quantity,  
              :signedby,
              :presence =>true                  

end
```

Item Model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :goods_in

attr_accessible :quantity,
              :partcode,
              :description,
              :goods_in_id


accepts_nested_attributes_for :goods_in


end
```

Goods In Controller:

```
def create
@goods_in = GoodsIn.new(params[:goods_in])
end
```

Comment: can you show the relevant controller code where you're calling new, create, or update_attributes ?

Comment: Added it to my question!

Answer (score 2):

you have to add

```
attr_accessible :items_attributes
```

And here's [a link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) to the documentation :)

Comment: could you please show me the params from the log that are being send ?

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GBf/8dANkgi9fCWfwluL3drfpksHMReBK1zJveswulE=",
 "goods_in"=>{"deliverydate"=>"",
 "deliverynoteno"=>"",
 "destination"=>"",
 "c4lpono"=>"",
 "courier"=>"",
 "notes"=>"",
 "signedby"=>"Carla Dessi",
 "items"=>{"partcode"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "quantity"=>"",
 "_destroy"=>""}},
 "suppliers"=>{"suppliername"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Submit Delivery",
 "collection"=>{"view"=>:get}}

Comment: You have something wrong with your associations and model names. It should be `has_many :items` and belongs_to :good_in. Could you send the full code of those two models ? I could help then :)

Comment: added it in to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an error in your Goods model.

It should read `has_many :items` instead of `has_many :item`.

Comment: I changed that and got this: `No association found for name item'. Has it been defined yet?`

Comment: What if you changed `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items` instead of `:item`.

Comment: if i change them both to items instead of item, the page loads but the fields don't show up, if i just change the accepts nested attributes part I get this: `No association found for name items'. Has it been defined yet?`

Comment: Additionally, in your item model, it should be `belongs_to :goods_in
`.

Comment: then i get `No association found for name 'goods_ins'. Has it been defined yet?`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve with your models but I think you want the folllowing:

Your  GoodsIn needs to have the relationship for accepts_nested_attributes_for :items . The belongs_to and accepts_nested_attributes_for is off.